# Angular jasmine how to assert httpclient is called with params object

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular11

I am new to writing tests mocking httpclient. I want to assert if httpclient is called with params object. I am trying the following and it doesnt works.

http call:

```
        this.http
            .get<boolean>(apiPath, {
                params: params,
                observe: 'response'
            })
            .pipe(
                map((response) => {
                    return response.body;
                })
            );
```

spect.ts

```
describe('PermissionExceptionService', () => {
    let service: PermissionExceptionService;
    let activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
    let spyHttpClient: jasmine.SpyObj<HttpClient>;
    let spyObservable: jasmine.SpyObj<Observable<string>>;
    let subscribeFunction: (value: string) => void;
    
    const activatedRouteStub = {
        snapshot: {
            paramMap : {
                get: () => 123,
                has: () => true
            },
            routeConfig: {
                path: 'do/:id'
            }
        }
    };

    beforeEach(() => {
        spyObservable = jasmine.createSpyObj('Observable', ['subscribe']);
        spyObservable.subscribe.and.callFake((f) => (subscribeFunction = f));
        spyHttpClient = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', {
            get: new Observable()
        });

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                PermissionExceptionService,
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteStub
                },
                {
                    provide: ENVIRONMENT,
                    useValue: { apiBaseUrl: 'https://api.example.com' }
                },
                {
                    provide: HttpClient,
                    useValue: spyHttpClient
                }                
            ]            
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(PermissionExceptionService);
        activatedRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    fit('should access control', () => {
        service.hasAccessControlException(activatedRoute.snapshot, [
            EnhancedAuditPermissions.View,
            EnhancedAuditPermissions.Create
        ]);

        expect(spyHttpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            'https://api.example.com/v1/session/permissions/exceptions/hasAccessControlException/',
            jasmine.objectContaining({params: auditInstanceId=123&activities=View&activities=Create, observe: 'response'})
        );        
    });    
});
```

Error i get:

```
Expected spy HttpClient.get to have been called with:
  [ 'https://api.example.com/v1/session/permissions/exceptions/hasAccessControlException/', <jasmine.objectContaining(Object({ activities: 'View', observe: 'response' }))> ]
but actual calls were:
  [ 'https://api.example.com/v1/session/permissions/exceptions/hasAccessControlException/', Object({ params: auditInstanceId=123&activities=View&activities=Create, observe: 'response' }) ].
```

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Why aren't you using https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests?

Comment: when i tried with httptestingcontroller, getting the followign error:
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match by function: ", found none.

Comment: The error shows you what the problem is, although it doesn't seem to match your example. It's unclear what went wrong with the other solution. Also I wouldn't recommend making a mock observable, just create a real one with `of`.